# what is the difference in memory pressure and disk pressure in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

While referring to the condition status of the nodes in Kubernetes, got confused with `MemoryPressure` and `DiskPressure`

This is the definition as per the docs : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/

```
MemoryPressure  True if pressure exists on the node memory – that is, if the node memory is low; otherwise False

DiskPressure    True if pressure exists on the disk size – that is, if the disk capacity is low; otherwise False

OutOfDisk   True if there is insufficient free space on the node for adding new pods, otherwise False
```

Question here is, what is different in node memory and disk size for kubernetes?

Comment: What puzzles you exactly? Difference between memory and disk capacity as such or the fact that disk has more statuses available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple terms:

- **Disk**: HDD        #e.g. 100GB of disk size
- **Memory**: RAM      #e.g. 4GB of memory

Comment: Incorrect. Kubernetes Disk resource is by no means ROM (Read Only Memory).

Comment: As I said, simple terms. Everyone understand ROM and RAM difference. Of course it is not read only. I have changed it by HDD, if it bothers you so strongly.

Comment: Thank you, analogy is now at least technically correct.